# Mathematics software to carry out iterations of Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: math-software

I made [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179036/solving-a-non-linear-multivariable-system-of-equations/) post a while ago, and I understand everything now. The problem is that I'm not sure what mathematics software I can use to generate the iterates like the user Amzoti did. His account has been suspended though, so I can't ask him unfortunately.

I've tried doing it manually, but it's too difficult to not make a mistake. I just want software or an online program that can make it easier. Preferably free or cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is excellent free (both as in free speech and as in free beer) software available that you can use for that purpose. I suggest [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student%2fNumericalAnalysis%2fNewton). I believe that is it.

Comment: I recommend you to learn Python or Scilab, there are two powerfull softwares, and they're open source, you can find them in $Linux$ or windows