# Using Jacobian Matrix to solve nonlinear system

Tags: newton-raphson, jacobian

I just read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Nonlinear_systems_of_equations) that Jacobian matrices can be used to solve a system of nonlinear equations, and I am wondering exactly how this might work. 
I have the following system to solve:

$$\frac{(1-x-2y-3z)(3-3x-2y-z)^3}{(4x)^4}-1=0$$
$$\frac{(1-x-2y-3z)(3-3x-2y-z)}{(2y)^2}-1=0$$
$$\frac{(1-x-2y-3z)^3(3-3x-2y-z)}{(4z)^4}-1=0$$
On the article that I linked, it states that a quick way to solve a non-linear system is by solving 
$$J_F(x_{n+1}-x_n)=-F(x_n)$$
I'm really not too sure what any of this means. I am familiar with the Jacobain matrix, as well as the standard Newton's method using $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$. What does $F(x)$ indicate in the above equation? Can someone provide an example of a simpler problem that uses this method?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179036/solving-a-non-linear-multivariable-system-of-equations

Comment: There are many solutions (also complex ones): $$x = 5.04835,y= 8.11751,z= -3.26314, \\x= -3.07816,y= 8.1143,z= 5.3475, \\ x= 0.554965,y= -0.892357,z= 0.358717,\\ x = -0.594701,y= 0.828277,z= -0.288399,\\x= -0.421321,y= 0.431613,z= 0.110539,\\x= 0.430132,y= 1.13386,z= 0.747241,\\x =  0.271627,y= 0.378312,z= -0.131725,\\x= 0.228651,y= 0.234236,z= 0.0599894$$

Comment: @Moo Thank you for your help. I see that there is only one answer in your list of solutions that satisfies $0<x,y,z<1$. Is there a way to show that that is the unique solution in $[0,1]^3$?

Comment: I am not sure, in 1 dimensional systems it relatively easy. I haven't looked at this in a very long time and I am not sure if the same is true in multidimensional systems.